# When does Emacs treat keymaps as functions?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys

Emacs' source code contains multiple instances of using `fset` with a keymap.

For example, in ediff-util.el:

```el
;; Allow ediff-mode-map to be referenced indirectly
(fset 'ediff-mode-map ediff-mode-map)
```

Or in esh-mode.el:

```el
(fset eshell-command-prefix (make-sparse-keymap))
```

Or compile.el:

```el
(defvar compilation-button-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [mouse-2] 'compile-goto-error)
    (define-key map [follow-link] 'mouse-face)
    (define-key map "\C-m" 'compile-goto-error)
    map)
  "Keymap for compilation-message buttons.")
(fset 'compilation-button-map compilation-button-map)
```

I've found examples in third-party elisp projects too, such as projectile. I've looked at the [creating keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Keymaps.html#Creating-Keymaps) documentation but I can't find anything relevant.

These values cannot even be called as functions:

```el
ELISP> (compilation-button-map)
*** Eval error ***  Invalid function: compilation-button-map
```

What's the purpose of setting the function slot of a symbol with a keymap? Where is it documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing new or unusual about this. This is how prefix keys work. They are bound to a keymap -- ***or*** they are bound to a symbol whose value ***or*** whose function definition is a keymap.

The Elisp manual node [Prefix Keys](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html) tells you this:

> The keymap binding of a prefix key is used for looking up the event
>   that follows the prefix key.  (***It may instead be a symbol whose function
>   definition is a keymap.***  The effect is the same, but the symbol serves
>   as a name for the prefix key.)  Thus, the binding of `C-x` is the symbol
>   `Control-X-prefix`, whose function cell holds the keymap for `C-x`
>   commands.  (The same keymap is also the value of *[variable]* `ctl-x-map`.)

Answer (score 1):

This was news to me. After doing some experiment it looks like it allows you to refer to a keymap *by name*.

```
(defun my-test () (interactive) (message "TEST TEST"))
(defvar my-test-mode t)
(defvar my-test-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(define-key my-test-map (kbd "C-c q") 'my-test)
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist '(my-test-mode . my-test-map))
```

If you press `C-c q`, Emacs informs that they binding is undefined.

Add the following:

```
(fset 'my-test-map my-test-map)
```

Now, the key binding is working.

My *guess* is that when the key lookup code find a symbol it looks at its function definition. If that looks like a keymap it will use it.

**Note:** You don't need to add a key binding *by name*. The standard way to add a keymap is by value:

```
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist (cons 'my-test-mode . my-test-map))
```

This will include the *value* of `my-test-map`. Since all functions binding keys destructively change the keymap, the change will take effect both in `my-test-map` and `minor-mode-map-alist`. The only drawback is that if you *reinitialize* the keymap variable, the old value will still be in `minor-mode-map-alist`. Effectively, it would appear as though new bindings wouldn't work.